# Non blocking CherryPy does not receive anything

Tags: python, webserver, cherrypy

I am trying to run cherrypy with cherrypy.engine.start instead of cherrypy.quickstart. That's because I want to run cherrypy in non blocking state to start and stop a web server within my functional tests with py.test.

This works fine:

```
cherrypy.quickstart(WebServerTest(None), config=testconf)
```

The response to a curl is:

```
curl --head http://127.0.0.1:1026/index HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: Thu, 08 Aug 2013 12:54:37 GMT
    Content-Length: 0
    Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
    Server: CherryPy/3.2.2
```

But it's blocking the rest of the script to execute.

However this does not work:

```
testconf = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'webservertest.conf')
web_server = WebServerTest(None)
cherrypy.tree.mount(web_server, "", config=testconf)
cherrypy.engine.start()
time.sleep(60)
cherrypy.engine.stop()
```

The response to a curl is:

```
curl --head http://127.0.0.1:1026/index
    curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

Adding cherrypy.engine.block() aftet cherrypy.engine.start does not solve the problem.

So how can I make it work with cherrypy.engine.start()?

The webservertest.conf config file is:

```
[global]
server.socket_host = "127.0.0.1"
server.socket_port = 1026
server.thread_pool = 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to pass the conf to `cherrypy.config.update(conf)`. This is for global config (including your server host and port), whereas the tree.mount call only sets config for that particular app. Read the source code of `quickstart` to see all the gory details.

Comment: That was it! Simply adding:
    cherrypy.config.update(testconf) made it work!
Thanks a lot!